# How to reconcile monthly expected vs actual amounts using query and vlookup?

Tags: google-sheets-formula, vlookup

Working on automating the categorisation of my monthly bank statement. Categorisation working well, where I am getting stuck though is reconciling each month with expected amount vs. actual.

I do have a workaround in that I use a query to return the amount for a specific month group by the category, and then I use vlookup to my expected list matching on the category and retuning the actual. Although this works, it just feels like it could be simpler. I have tried using query and adding another condition, i.e. where category on the bank statement is the same as in my list of categories used to list the expected values. As this is per month, I include a pivot on the date (year, month). That works in that it then returns the value per month using my category list to match the category from the bank statement. The issue with this is because of the pivot, if I do this for each item on my category list, the months will be repeated with the value on the next line.

The other option is to return the category group by month, and then somehow sequence the order of the returned categories and values to my list of categories.

Included link to example sheet. Open to other suggestions

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IqwVkYAt2c6Ng7vfv5AZNY_xR98RygqqXSDbmhVAkF4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: From the tag wiki for [tag:google-sheets] and [tag:google-sheets-formula]: *Do NOT share spreadsheets/images as the only source of data. Use markdown TEXT tables instead.* Also see [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try:

```
=index(let(Σ,unique(eomonth(torow(A2:A,1),),1),
             {text(Σ,"mmm yy");makearray(counta(E2:E),counta(Σ),lambda(r,c,sumifs(C:C,B:B,index(E2:E,r),eomonth(A:A,),index(Σ,,c))))}))
```

- *It will expand automatically to rightwards n' downside* if and when `new expenses OR months are added` to the bank statement raw data accommodated in `Columns A:C`

[image]

Comment: no idea what that formula is doing but it works exactly like I was hoping. Thank you so so so much @rockinfreakshow

Comment: A small tweak is needed, can I reverse the order of the dates generated in the column to go from latest to oldest?

Comment: Replace this part of the formula `torow(A2:A,1)` with `torow(sort(A2:A,1,),1)`